# Using GS register from user level in X64 Linux

Tags: c++, llvm, x86-64, cpu-registers, memory-segmentation

I am trying to use `%gs` register to save a temporary value in my program. I am using LLVM pass to insert assembly code that writes to and reads the registers. When I use `%fs`, everything works. But `%fs` is used by a few programs/libraries, while `%gs` is not.

When I replace `%fs` by `%gs`, even simple instructions like `mov %eax, %gs:0x0` fail.

```
 mov    %rbx,%fs:0x0 //Works
 mov    %rbx,%gs:0x0 //Segmentation Fault.
```

(On the other hand, `mov %rbx, %gs` works as long as value in `%eax` is less than 4. Any value more than 4, gives segmentation fault)

How can I create segment and use its segment selector in `%gs` that I can use further in the program.

Machine Desc: 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04. llvm-7.0.1

Comment: You're looking for documented, universally available, convenient, unused storage. Sorry. There is no such thing. A little extra storage can help with performance, and people have been trying to boost performance for decades. I'm afraid that your only option is [alloca](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1AllocaInst.html), which is quite a bit less convenient.

Answer (score 0):

What ABI are you using? Check this out https://www.codemachine.com/article_x64deepdive.html "... but on the X64, it is the GS register that points to the TEB while in user mode ..."

I would say that this is not possible with the X64 ABI.

Comment: Thanks for the link and reply. I am using c++ to wite an LLVM pass. At this point, I simply need a register to save some information during my program execution. I looked through application and lib binaries and none used %gs register. Is there any other register that can be used for this purpose then. Also, %gs always seems to have 0 value. And even when I write to it, there is no crash. Overwriting TEB should crash my program. Am I understanding it right.

Comment: The ABI docs say, from memory that in linux, in kernel mode, this is used 100%. In user mode there are some cases where the thread environment is not used.